# Predict function tuning for random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I have created a random forest object in R (using the `randomForest` package) with `ntree = N`. Now I would like to predict some new data on it using a subset of `N`, that is using only `n` trees for the prediction. Is this possible?

For the random forest object the forest is located at `fit$forest`, but I don't know how to extract them (if possible).

Comment: Can you maybe explain why you want to do that? Generally the more trees you use, the better is your prediction.

Comment: Let's say I found that some trees are better than others so I only want to use the "good" ones.

Comment: How did you find out, that they are better?

Comment: Suppose I did..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to set `predict.all = TRUE`. This will cause `predict.randomForest` to return a list containing a vector of the aggregate predictions and a matrix of the individual tree predictions. You can then ensemble the individual trees at your leisure.

```
library("randomForest")
data(mtcars)

rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars, ntree = 10)
preds <- predict(rf, newdata = mtcars, predict.all = TRUE)

preds$aggregate   # Aggregate predictions
preds$individual  # Invididual tree predictions
```

Make sure you set `newdata = <something>` or this trigger fails for some reason.

Comment: I had hoped for a more automated process but this will do just fine.

Comment: More automated in what sense?

Comment: As in a parameter that you could set inside the predict function that would choose the subset.

Comment: From the matrix, that's easy :). https://gist.github.com/DexGroves/d6c055addf870b30d678862cc0fa8a88

Comment: I will use that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so for your usecase you can set `predict.all = TRUE` when predicting on new data (see the help file via `?predict.randomForest`). Then you get a list element called `individual`, which contains the prediction of each tree.